# how to do a horizontal line with "=" between it?

Tags: tables, amsmath, line, comparison, horizontal

i can not find how to connect 2 variables with a horizontal line with a "=" inbetween.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  When you post a question, please post what actual code you're using in a minimal working example, and tell us what you've tried and how exactly it's failing.  Otherwise, we have to do all the work; that makes it much less likely anyone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Here you are.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}  

    \node [anchor=base] at (0,0) (a) {$a$};
    \node [anchor=base] at (1,0) (b) {$b$};
    \node at (0.5,-0.3) (neq) {\color{Brown}$\neq$};

    \draw[Brown] (a) |- (neq) -| (b);   

    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't like the color I picked, you may refer to [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors) to see how you can compose what you'd prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a non-`tikz` solution. It should work well if you intend to use that in display math environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\lelbow}{\rule[1.5pt]{.4pt}{3pt}\makebox[0pt][l]{\rule[1.5pt]{4pt}{.4pt}}}
\newcommand{\relbow}{\makebox[0pt][r]{\rule[1.5pt]{4pt}{.4pt}}\rule[1.5pt]{.4pt}{3pt}}
\newcommand{\underneq}[3][Black]{\mathord{%
    \makebox[.5\width]{\phantom{\(#2\)}}%
    \underset{%
        \color{#1}\lelbow\hfill\neq\hfill\relbow%
    }{%
        \makebox[.5\width][r]{\(#2\)}%
        \mathrel{\phantom{\neq}}%
        \makebox[.5\width][l]{\(#3\)}%
    }%
    \makebox[.5\width]{\phantom{\(#3\)}}%
}}
\begin{document}
\[
\underneq[Sepia]{a}{b} \qquad
\underneq{M}{i}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks that helped me a lot!! but how can i choose by myself where to put the end of the bows. e.g 'a b c d' and I want to connect 'a' and 'd'.

Comment: @wowowo When I defined this command I didn't think there would be anything between the elements connected, so I think it would require a different implementation, probably a little more complicated. Also, I think it requires more information. What kind of expressions do you want to connect? How long could they be? Should the horizontal part of the bows stretch according to the width of the expression between the elements connected, or it doesn't matter if only the spacing stretches?

Comment: i want to connect letters that are seperated with a space. like in my example. but the positions I want to connect can be different. e.g 'a b c d e' connect 'a' and 'd'. and yes, the horizontal part should stretch between the 2 variables and the = should be in the middle. it's hard to describe.. sorry for that!